# Do users of a program you made need access to a local machine for some functions and would that work in limited XP account?

Tags: java, javascript, android-emulator, windows-xp

Read an interesting article about securing XP,http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/software/1304965/when-windows-xp-support-ends-this-is-how-you-secure-your-pc-and-save-all-updates.

With these suggestions is building apps for the marketplace ok with this setup to get by w/o headaches.

Here are my noob thoughts and question:

Just learning to code. Do you think I could run a limited setup to learn languages Java and C# while still being able to use my desktop for deployment of apps? A limited login as described only allows certain actions which I believe is different than a typical guest account.  I wonder if my comp could still act as a server to retrieve data requested by users away from my machine. I figure I would need to be logged in as an admin to make some changes but, would hope that tasking processes or jobs could still be done.

I guess my question is, do users of a program you made need access to a local machine for some functions and would that work in limited?

I would like to get something portable and keep my desktop for business to be economical and not run the risk of logging on to an unsecure Wi-Fi with a portable that has business use. Ideally, I'd pony up for newer, better. I'm just learning though.

Answer (score 0):

> Do users of a program you made need access to a local machine for some functions and would that work in limited.

No. If you need some sort of server backend for your app a personal computer would be a bad choice for several reasons:

- It would need to be available at all times: you can't frequently turn it off or restart.
- It would require the same ip address.
- It could consume a good amount of you're computer's resources, making it difficult to use for personal use

Instead you should probably be using a dedicated server or a cloud based solution, of which several offer free usage tiers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am aware of that and could satisfy those conditions with my old desktop. The portable would be for personal use. My concern is securing XP to do this specifically in the manner that the article states.  I guess you are suggesting to not use a desktop at all and go with a more professional network?

Comment: @user3880718 If all you're using it for is to write code, you should be fine. It could potentially be a concern if you were allowing external sources to connect to it.

Comment: I am not sure if my app will eventually need to go that far. I think what I have in mind will just require user memory. Off topic, do you think the version of Unix for XP will eventually cause compatibility issues with Java code for apps or is it not even an issue? Thank you. It's interesting to see how long you can make something work for.  I tried to vote up but, need 15 reputation.  I'm holding off on best to see about XP.  I won't hold my breath as my question is antiquated.

Comment: Another option would be to install Linux, which in my opinion is nicer to develop on than Windows.